# Windows application can't write to remote console

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I have a simple function to initialize console in application compiled with "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" option:

```
bool InitConsole()
{
    HANDLE consoleHandleOut, consoleHandleErr;

    //we run only in console
    if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
        return false;

    consoleHandleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    consoleHandleErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

    if ((consoleHandleOut != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    && (consoleHandleErr != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
    {
        freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w+", stdout);
        freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w+", stderr);
        setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    }
    else
        return false;    

    return true;
}
```

This function works well, when I run an application using PowerShell or CMD on any local computer. However, I need to run this app using remote PowerShell/Cmd, which has started using this piece of code:

```
STARTUPINFO ini_processo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processo_info;
memset(&ini_processo, 0, sizeof(ini_processo));

ini_processo.cb = sizeof(ini_processo);
ini_processo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
ini_processo.hStdInput = ini_processo.hStdOutput = ini_processo.hStdError = (HANDLE)ConnectSocket;
ini_processo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

if (CreateProcess(NULL, PSPath, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &ini_processo, &processo_info))
{
    CloseHandle(processo_info.hThread);
    CloseHandle(processo_info.hProcess);
}
```

I use ConnectSocket handle to get all output. After closing process handles, program exits immediately to leave powershell with connected socket. So, later I run my app using this powershell and expect to get some output.

It does work with any application compiled for console subsystem as well it works with any commands like ls, ps, dir, etc. But it does not work with my program. Function InitConsole() always returns TRUE. I can write console like always using "fprintf(stdout, fmt, ##**VA_ARGS**)", but I have no output at all. I feel like I write to "another" console, because I do not get errors.

Why is my program does not display anything?

Answer (score -1):

> I can write console like always using "fprintf(stdout, fmt,
> ##VA_ARGS)", but I have no output at all. I feel like I write to "another" console, because I do not get errors.

When you launch cmd.exe, you then exit from your app immediately, which closes the socket. You need to keep the socket open for the lifetime of the cmd.exe process.

Modify:

```
CloseHandle(processo_info.hThread);
WaitForSingleObject(processo_info.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(processo_info.hProcess);
```

Comment: This is not right. Socket has been duplicated to app which runs cmd. Please, have a look at CreateProcess params. I wrote, that everything works well, except my program.

Comment: @David Maybe you can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58278889/11128312